# Executing a function with setInterval

Tags: javascript, setinterval

**Trying to run a function that executes every few seconds after a condition is met** *(enemy.y > 195)*.

**What happens in the logs**:

-When the condition is met, it waits 3 seconds (so good right) and then executes the function rapidly (not good) even though I'm using clearInterval method.

-I want it to execute the function just once (not rapidly) every 3 seconds.

So, there are two functions in this scenario.

**First function** is the function being executed.

**Second function** is using the setInterval method to execute the function after 3s.

```
function enemyAttack1() {
  playerHealth -= enemyStrike;
};


function enemyAttack2() {
  if (enemy.y > 195) {
    const strikeTimer = setInterval(enemyAttack1, 3000);
    clearInterval(strikeTimer);
  }
};
```

Comment: What calls enemyAttack2. Is it possible that it's being called a lot, and when you set your interval, you actually setting the interval many times back to back?

Comment: You are clearing your interval immediately after you create it. So I wonder how `enemyAttack1` would ever be called ... Probably you want to use `setTimeout` instead

Comment: if you want the function to be called once only after the given time, you should use `setTimeout`. But anyway why do you call `clearInterval` right after setting it? The function does it even get called once?

Comment: The two call to `clearInterval()` cancels the call to `setInterval()` and `enemyAttack1` is never called because of the interval. Maybe you call it from another part of the code.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need something like this.

```js
    let playerHealth = 100;
    let enemyStrike = 2;
    let enemy = { x: 0, y: 200 };
    
    function enemyAttack1() {
      playerHealth -= enemyStrike;
      enemy.y -= 5;
      console.log({
        playerHealth,
        enemy
      })
    };
    
    
    function enemyAttack2() {
    
      if (enemy.y > 195) {
       const strikeTimer = setInterval(() => {
       // stopping condition if needed. But this will be checked in the next run only so one last value with 180 will be printed
          if (enemy.y <= 180) {
            clearInterval(strikeTimer);
          }else{
             enemyAttack1()
          }
          
        }, 3000);
      }
    };
    
    enemyAttack2();
```

Answer (score 0):

The call to `clearInterval()` cancels the effects of `setInterval()` and `enemyAttack1()` is never called.

Run the following snippet. I added logging here and there to be clear what happens. `enemyAttack1()` executes only once, when it is called explicitly by the main code.

If you see the effects of `enemyAttack1()` in your program then maybe it is called from another part of the code.

```js
let playerHealth = 1000;
let enemyStrike = 5;
let enemy = { x: 0, y: 200 };

function enemyAttack1() {
  console.log('This is enemyAttack1()');
  playerHealth -= enemyStrike;
  console.log({ playerHealth });
};


function enemyAttack2() {
  console.log('This is enemyAttack2()');
  if (enemy.y > 195) {
    console.log('starting attack');
    const strikeTimer = setInterval(enemyAttack1, 3000);
    clearInterval(strikeTimer);
    console.log('/starting attack');
  }
};

enemyAttack1();
console.log('here');
enemyAttack2();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use setTimeOUt instead of using setInteval if you want execute just for once

```
strikeTimer= setTimeout(enemyAttack1(){
 playerHealth -= enemyStrike
  },3000);
```